# Joining two images in java - an orange background is added

Tags: java, image, pdfbox

This question is similar to…

> [Java BufferedImage saves with unwanted background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410996)

…but regards `.jpg` and not `.png`.

I join two images together using the following Java code, and an orange background is mysteriously added. How can I get rid of it?

Note that I am trying to cover my bases using both `setColor` and `setBackground`, and both `clearRect` and `fillRect`.

Note that the source of the two images is a PDF, extracted using PDFBox

```java
public static BufferedImage joinBufferedImage(BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2) {
    int offset = 0;
    int width = Math.max(img1.getWidth() , img2.getWidth()) + offset;
    int height = img1.getHeight() + img2.getHeight() + offset;

    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = newImage.createGraphics();

    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    g2.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    g2.drawImage(img1, null, 0, 0);
    g2.drawImage(img2, null, 0, img1.getHeight() + offset);
    g2.dispose();

    return newImage;
}
```

```java
BufferedImage joined = joinBufferedImage(bim, bim2);
ImageIO.write(joined, "jpg", imageFile);
```

Comment: Couldn't you use `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` because the alpha transparency does not exist in JPEG images?

Comment: That works! Please post as an answer and I will mark it correct! (And thanks for your editing...I will try and format better next time....)